# PayPal chained payment error 550001

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

I made an REST application and I successfully perform chained payments in sandbox, but when I try to make chained payments in live environment I got the following error:

```
(  
[Receiver] =>  
[Category] => Application  
[Domain] => PLATFORM  
[ErrorID] => 550001  
[ExceptionID] =>  
[Message] => User is not allowed to perform this action  
[Parameter] => Chained Payment  
[Severity] => Error  
[Subdomain] => Application  
)
```

What I need to do in order to obtain the appropriate permissions for executing the chained payments ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to make sure:

- Check the status of your application, you will need to login to
  apps.paypal.com and see if you have selected `Chain Payments` when
  you submitted your app.
- Make sure your PayPal account is confirmed and verified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but does the link that you give me is for rest the applications? I selected web application and chained payments were checked.

Comment: can you provide the correlation id that you got in response?